# Displayed some of entry in model.forms

Tags: html, django, forms

My table contain three fields.
id , name, status

When,I do this `{{ form|bootstrap }}`, it shows all field.
name is drop-down in html.
I want to display only those entry whose status = 1.?

Comment: You should filter your objects by `status=1` in your view

Comment: I used it directly in html

Answer (score 0):

Please add filter in form class **init** method,

so that you will only get status=1 in html.

Or you can try ajax.